# How to filter by boolean expression accessing variable from controller inside a ng.repeat filter?

Tags: angularjs

How do I filter by a boolean expression from a variable that is declared in the controller?

something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{someVarFromController==true}">
    <div>
      {{user.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I manage it to work only then the expression is using the collection property
ex:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{IsDomestic: true}">
```

Comment: Not the same but close.

Comment: I beg a pardon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function in your controller that returns true or false for a particular element, and use that in the filter.

```
$scope.showUser = function(user){
    // logic to decide if element should be displayed, or just:
    return $scope.someVarFromController;    
};
```

---

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:showUser">
```

An observation : maybe I am missing something, but I'm not sure why you would want to filter by just a variable in `$scope`, with no reference to the particular elements from the `ng-repeat`. That way either all your elements will be shown, or none of them, and in that case you are better off using `ng-if` or `ng-show` at a higher level.